# how to put element into <div> by innerHTML or other ways?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```js
var turn = 1;
var boardPiece;
var piece = [];
function init() {
  boardPiece = document.getElementById("pages");
  while (boardPiece.firstElementChild) {
    if (typeof boardPiece.firstElementChild.id != 'undefined') {
      piece.push(boardPiece.firstElementChild);
    }
    boardPiece.removeChild(boardPiece.firstElementChild);
  }
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = piece[0]; //My problem is here
}
init();
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="pages">
  <div id="page1" class="page">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="page2" class="page">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

The result is a text

> [object HTMLDivElement]

not an element.

What's wrong with my `.innerHTML`? And what is `typeof piece[0]`? Is it `text`?

Comment: piece[0].innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your:

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = piece[0];
```

with:

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = piece[0].innerHTML;
```

What you are trying to do atm is to insert element (which is an object) as a plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `.innerHTML` along with your `piece[0]` variable like,

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = piece[0].innerHTML;
```

**Working Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/gs0yy50t/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the type of `piece[0]` is not a string, but a HTML element. For that reason, in order to assign it to the content's innerHTML (which is a string), JavaScript is implicitly calling the `piece[0].toString()` method.

When calling the `toString()` method in HTML nodes (like most non-string objects in JavaScript), it [returns a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) representing the type of the object.

If you need to add the **element** `piece[0]` as child of `content`, then you should do:

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = piece[0].outerHTML;
```

However, if what you need is to copy the **content** of one element into another, you should use the property `innerHTML` instead:

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = piece[0].innerHTML;
```

Basically, both properties are strings with the HTML code of the element but `outerHTML` includes the element itself in the root.

Comment: My need is outerHTML.

Comment: Your answer is so nice!!^^

Comment: Consider marking it as best answer if this solved the issue :)